# Perfect Secrecy in Symmetric Key Systems

Tags: symmetric

For symmetric key systems does perfect secrecy imply that all ciphers in the cipher space are equiprobable?

I would think not, but I am finding it hard to come up with a counter example.

Comment: This comes down to definitions... Do you mean all ciphertexts in the set of possible ciphertexts? Or can the ciphertext space be larger than the plaintext space?

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. Consider the following perfectly secret probabilistic encryption scheme. Encrypt exactly like a one-time pad. Then, with probability 1/4 add a 0-bit after the ciphertext, and with probability 3/4 add a 1-bit after the ciphertext. For decryption, first throw away the last bit, and then decrypt as in the one-time pad. The ciphertexts in the ciphertext space are now *not* equiprobable.

Having said this, Shannon's theorem says that when the message space, ciphertext space and key spaces are all the same size, then a scheme is perfectly secret if and only if every key is chosen with the same probability and every plaintext and ciphertext have a single key mapping one to the other. A simple corollary from this theorem says that in this case (where all spaces are the same size) then the ciphertext values are all equiprobable.